# Recommended index and query improvement

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have this cross server query that inserts a large amount of rows from our log database to our data warehouse.  The problem is right now the job is running over 15 hours.  Need to drastically reduce this.  Need advice on the best index for this query or if any improvements can be made on the query itself.  I'm thinking an index on URL, Timestamp for the fromDatabase and ID Timestamp for toDatabase.  But not sure on the best order of the key columns or if I should use included, etc.  All help is greatly appreciated.

```
  SELECT @SQL = N'
    INSERT INTO ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log
        (
        ImportDateTime
        ,ServerSource
        ,DatabaseSource
        ,Id
        ,Type
        ,UserName
        ,AppCode                        
        ,SubscriptionCode
        ,Duration
        ,ServiceNamespace
        ,ServiceName
        ,MethodName
        ,Parameters
        ,[Message]
        ,StackTrace
        ,Url
        ,UrlReferrer
        ,Browser
        ,BrowserVersion
        ,Platform
        ,Timestamp
        ,IpAddress
        ,EriAccountId
        )
        (
            SELECT
            ''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@ImportDateTime) + '''
            ,''' +  @ServerSource + '''
            ,''' +  @DatabaseSource + '''
            ,Id
            ,Type
            ,UserName
            ,AppCode
            ,SubscriptionCode
            ,Duration
            ,ServiceNamespace
            ,ServiceName
            ,MethodName
            ,Parameters
            ,Message
            ,StackTrace
            ,Url
            ,UrlReferrer
            ,Browser
            ,BrowserVersion
            ,Platform
            ,Timestamp
            ,IpAddress
            ,EriAccountId

         FROM (
                select
                Id
                ,Type
                ,UserName
                ,AppCode
                ,SubscriptionCode
                ,Duration
                ,ServiceNamespace
                ,ServiceName
                ,MethodName
                ,Parameters
                ,Message
                ,StackTrace
                ,Url
                ,UrlReferrer
                ,Browser
                ,BrowserVersion
                ,Platform
                ,Timestamp
                ,IpAddress
                ,EriAccountId

    from openquery([' + @ServerSource + '],
                    ''select 
                    Id
                    ,Type
                    ,UserName
                    ,AppCode
                    ,SubscriptionCode
                    ,Duration
                    ,ServiceNamespace
                    ,ServiceName
                    ,MethodName
                    ,[Parameters] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),[Parameters])
                    ,[Message]
                    ,StackTrace
                    ,Url
                    ,UrlReferrer
                    ,Browser
                    ,BrowserVersion
                    ,Platform
                    ,Timestamp
                    ,IpAddress
                    ,EriAccountId           
                    FROM ' + @FromDatabase + '.dbo.[Log] WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE URL LIKE ''''http://online%'''' AND CONVERT(DATETIME2, TimeStamp) > ''''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@AssessorDeploymentTimestamp) + ''''' AND CONVERT(DATETIME2,TimeStamp) > ''''' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@DateCollected) + ''''' '') o
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT 1
                        FROM ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.Log b 
                        WHERE b.id = o.id
                        AND CONVERT(DATETIME2, b.TimeStamp) > ''' +  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@DateCollected) + '''
                        AND b.ServerSource = ''' +  @ServerSource + '''
                        )

                ) a
        )'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'm going to say that you should follow some tips for optimizing query execution time besides implementing a correct index strategy.

- Avoid functions in the inner SELECT and JOIN statements. Functions (even when cached) should be executed for the lowest amount possible of records and, usually, this happens in the outermost select.
- Avoid subqueries when possible, chose JOIN instead.
- Avoid using non numeric fields in the where statements when possible, an index scan on an INT field is much much faster than on a VARCHAR.
- Avoid using the WITH(NOLOCK) hint since you will also read uncommitted data. It doesn't make the query go faster and you'll have a potential dirty dataset.

When trying to optimize a query also keep in mind the order of operation that the query "interpreter" uses to parse it:

1. FROM and JOIN BLOCK
2. GROUP BY AND HAVING
3. WHERE
4. SELECT

So try to write your query to reduce the number or records returned by each of this block in THIS order.

That being said, an INDEX must be created according to the query that uses and you can find an helpful hint if you test a query execution with the execution plan included, often SSMS helps you a lot.

In this case I'd add an index on the *URL* and *TimeStamp* fields, in that order

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Log ON yourDatabase.dbo.[log] (URL, Timestamp)
```